# Getting memory fault when reading command line arguments in a C++ program

Tags: c++, unix, memory

I've been writing a C++ code project for school that wants me to read a text file from a command line argument and output it along with adding adjectives declared in the command line after any articles [a,an,the]. This is the first time I have to use the command line for any project.

I've managed to get and read the text file from the command line but my problem is when I want to get a string as a parameter of a function isArticle(), I keep getting the following message in the UNIX shell:

```
./test-program1[38]: eval: line 1: 7704: Memory fault
0a1,4
```

I don't suspect that the problem is with the `isArticle()` function but here it is:

```
bool isArticle(string n)
{
    string article[]={"a","an","the","A","An","aN","AN","The","tHe","thE","THe","tHE","ThE","THE"};

    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(article);i++)
    {
        if(n.compare(article[i])==0)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

While it's not complete, here's some test code that I use to see if the isArticle() function is working:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    istream *br;
    ifstream file;

    if(argc == 1)
        br = &cin;
    else if(argc==3)
    {
        file.open(argv[2]);
        if(file.is_open())//put work here
        {
            br=&file;
            string word;
            string output[sizeof(file)];
            while(file>>word)
            {
                if(isArticle(word)==true)
                {
                    cout<<word;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            usage(argv[2],"Cannot open "+string(argv[2]));
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        usage(argv[1], "More than one filename was given");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check what `sizeof(article)` and `sizeof(file)` do (not what you seem to think.)

Comment: To amplify on what juanchopanza said, `sizeof(article)` is going to be quite a lot bigger than 14, but that's how many strings are defined in the array.  It was a good thing you included the `isArticle()` function since that is the source of the trouble — so thank you for including it.  When you have the array definition in a function like that, the number of elements in an array is `sizeof(article) / sizeof(article[0])`.  This does not work for array parameters to functions; then the calling code needs to pass the size explicitly.

Comment: If you `transform` the string to all lower case or all upper case, you won't need as many comparisons.  Search for "c++ transform tolower toupper"

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Transforming strings like that is not something for a beginner.  Generically, `std::transform` can't be used, since there's no one to one mapping between upper and lower case.  But even in simple cases like his (which is obviously just handling English language text), there are gotchas.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The problem isn't just with `sizeof( article )`; it's also with `sizeof( file )`.  Which needs a different solution; his problem requires `std::vector<std::string>` in the main.

Comment: @JamesKanze: since the array `output` (which is given the dimension `sizeof(file)`) isn't actually used, it doesn't seem likely to be the one causing the trouble.  However, you're right; there seems to be a general misunderstanding of `sizeof`, but that was what juanchopanza said first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator doesn't return the number of elements in the array.  It returns the memory space occupied by the array.  An array of `char` will have a different `sizeof` than an array of `int`.

For your array you can determine number of elements at compile time by:

```
const unsigned int elements_in_array =
    sizeof(article) / sizeof(article[0]);
```

Comment: Be very careful using `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`; it's dangerous.  If the array has decayed to a pointer, it will still compile, but it won't do what you want.  C++11 has `std::begin` and `std::end` for this; pre-C++11, of course, we all had something equivalent in our toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, `sizeof` does *not* give the number
of elements in an array; the idiomatic way of doing so is to use
`std::end( article ) - std::begin( article )`.  In pre-C++11, most
experienced C++ programmers would do the same, using the versions of
`begin` and `end` from their toolkit.

The entire `isArticle` function is highly unidiomatic.  In C++11, the
entire function would be a single library call:

```
bool
isArticle( std::string const& word )
{
    static std::string const articles[] = {
        "a", "an", "the", "A", "An", "aN", "AN",
        "The", "tHe", "thE", "THe", "tHE", "ThE", "THE",
    };
    return std::any_of(
            std::begin( articles ), std::end( articles ),
            [=]( std::string const& target ) { return word == target; } );
}
```

In earlier C++, we'd have written:

```
return std::find( begin( articles ), end( articles ), word )
        != end( articles );
```

(with `begin` and `end` from our usual toolkit).  And if we wanted (for
pedagogical reasons) to write the loop ourselves, it would be something
like:

```
std::string::const_iterator current = std::begin( articles );
std::string::const_iterator end = std::end( articles );
while ( current != end && *current != word ) {
    ++ current;
}
return current != end;
```

Several points not really related to your immediate problem are probably
worth mentionning:

- Class types are normally passed by reference to const, rather than by
  value.  This is, arguably, premature optimization, but it is so
  ubiquitous that anything else makes one wonder why.
- Values that are not changed in the function should be declared `const`
  *and* `static`.
- `std::string` supports `==` and `!=`; if you're looking for equality,
  that's what you should be using.  The `compare` function should really
  only be used for lexicographic ordering.
- Returning from the middle of a loop is something you generally want to
  avoid.  Of course, when functions are this simple, it really doesn't
  matter, but it's a bad habit to get into.

This just concerns the function in question.  In the `main`, you also
have the problem with `sizeof`.  In this case, it looks like you're
trying to use it to determine the number of words in the file.  That
cannot be done without actually reading the file.  What you need here is
`std::vector<std::string>`, and not a C style array (whose size must be
known at compile time).

And of course: the type needed for an `if` is `bool`.  `isArticle`
returns a `bool`, so nothing else is needed.  Writing 
`isArtile( word ) == true` strongly suggests that you don't know what a
`bool` type is.  (Hint: the type of the expression 
`isArtile( word ) == true` is also `bool`.)

And one final suggestion: if there are no arguments to the program, you
don't do anything.  Which I don't think is the intent.  The usual
solution for command line processes under Unix (and it's also widespread
under Windows) is to put all of the actual work in a function, and write
something like:

```
int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc == 1 ) {
        process( std::cin );
    } else {
        for ( int i = 1; i != argc; ++ i ) {
            std::ifstream in( argv[i] );
            if ( ! in ) {
                //  Output error message and set global flag for
                //  return value...
            } else {
                process( in );
            }
        }
    }
    return globalFlagWithReturnValue;
}
```

The function `process` takes an `std::istream&` as argument, which
allows it to read either `std::cin` or an opened `std::istream`.

Comment: I don't understand.  The code you posted has `ostream` derivates, yet the sentence afterward talks about `istream`.  Which is it?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't know what I was thinking of.  It obviously should be `istream` derivates `std::cin` and `std::ifstream` (since these are the inputs).  I've fixed it.  Thanks.